# add timestamps to recorded session via "script" command

Tags: terminal, logs, timestamps, typescript

In my .bash_profile I have `script -a -t 0 session.log` which automatically records all terminal input/output into the session.log file. I know this command comes with an optional flag to record the time differences in another file but I was wondering if there was another way to prefix the session.log lines with a timestamp.

Can I pipe the writes to a different shell function before writing it to session.log? Something like this `script -a >(add_timestamps.sh >> session.log)` (does not work)

Comment: Is there anything special in the format about these script files, or could this question be reworded to be about prepending timestamps to *files in general*?

Comment: ideally I would like the timestamp to be as automated and simple as possible so i'm trying to avoid tailing the file and then writing to a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably only one thing missing from your example, the option `-f` to flush the write each time.

```
script -f >(while read;do date;echo "$REPLY";done >>session.log)
```

Comment: Wow you're right... I was closer than I realized.. for osx however you have to do `script -t 0` to flush each time. I also ended up going with this function to add the date... http://serverfault.com/a/310104

Answer (score 1):

this might be a partial solution, depending on your needs: if you include \d \D{} in your PS1 string, each command prompt will include the date and time. that will give you the time at which the previous command finished.
in the simplest case, do

```
    PS1='\d \D{} $ '
```

do that after invoking script (or in your .bashrc or whatever) and you will get a session.log like this:

```
    Wed Apr 20 08:23:55 PM $ date
    Wed Apr 20 20:23:57 EDT 2016
    Wed Apr 20 08:23:57 PM $ exit
```

Comment: This is pretty slick but I don't want to pollute the Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `ts`, from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

Lots of distros have it packaged. It just prepends timestamps to lines of input.

Example use:

```
$ while true; do sleep 1; echo hi; done | ts %s
1461198715 hi
1461198716 hi
1461198717 hi
1461198718 hi
[ ... ]
```

Comment: The code needs to be portable and not just for local use so I can't assume everyone will have it installed

Answer (score 0):

By using awk as the log output destination, you can add a timestamp to the beginning of each line.

```
script -fq >(awk '{print strftime("%F %T ") $0}{fflush() }'>> session.log)
```

Example)

```
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# LANG=C script -fq >(awk '{print strftime("%F %T ") $0}{fflush() }'>>
session.log)
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]#
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# echo aaa
aaa
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]#
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# exit
exit
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]#
[root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# cat session.log
2017-05-26 01:12:11 Script started on Fri May 26 01:12:11 2017
2017-05-26 01:12:13 [root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# pwd
2017-05-26 01:12:13 /root
2017-05-26 01:12:14 [root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]#
2017-05-26 01:12:16 [root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# echo aaa
2017-05-26 01:12:16 aaa
2017-05-26 01:12:16 [root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]#
2017-05-26 01:12:17 [root@BS-PUB-CENT7-01 ~]# exit
2017-05-26 01:12:17 exit
```

Comment: Please add some explanation if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not good at English...